# insert current date in a place of empty column (field) of a file

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, date

I have a file with four columns delimited by "|" as below

```
23414|test doc for me||
32322|test doc for you|2004_12_03|
13454|test doc for all||2010_11_01
```

I am trying to insert the current system date to the empty columns so that output should looks like as

```
23414|test doc for me|2018_04_03|2018_04_03
32322|test doc for you|2004_12_03|2018_04_03
13454|test doc for all|2018_04_03|2010_11_01
```

below is the code which I have tried

```
for file in `ls -rlt Added_to_* | awk '{print $9}'`
do
  now="$(date +'%Y/%m/%d')"
  echo "Running for: $file"
  awk -F'|' -v curr="$now" '{ 
    if( $3=="" || $4=="" ){ 
     if ( $3=="" ) { print "$curr"}
     if ( $4=="" ) { print "$curr"}
  }else  
     do_something ; 
  }' $file 
done
```

Comment: i have edited the question with the code,i'm trying

Comment: `+'%d/%m/%Y'` doesn't seem to the date format you say you want, and what is `do_something` in the else block?

Comment: do_something can be any statement like as echo "do_something"

Comment: You are one year ahead!

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no need to parse the output of `ls` or even to use a shell loop at all - since `awk` can read and process a list of files.

Another issue is the way you are referring to the passed variable: `$curr` should simply be `curr` (`$curr` would refer to a *field numbered* `curr` - if such a thing exisited). Also there's no need to test the emptiness of the fields twice.

So

```
awk -v curr="$now" '
  BEGIN{OFS=FS="|";} {for(i=3;i<=4;i++) {if ($i=="") $i=curr}} {print}
' Added_to_*
```

Answer (score 0):

We use of the lookbehind/lookahead regexes to zero in on the POI (positions of interest) where the substitution will happen. Once there, we place the current date using `Perl's` builtin `localtime` function. The 3rd, 4th, & 5th fields are the day/mm/yy info to which we add the required constants to get today's date. To the year we add `1900`, to month 1, and 0 to day,

```
perl -ple 's/\|\K(?=\||$)/join "_", map $_ + qw[1900 1 0][$a++%3], (localtime)[5,4,3]/eg'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sed ":a;s/|\(|\|$\)/|$(date +%Y_%m_%d)\1/;ta"
```

as Costas say

should help you.

PS. Sorry. Looks like you dont use double dash for splitting. Let me think...

Comment: `sed ":a;s/|\(|\|$\)/|$(date +%Y_%m_%d)\1/;ta"`

Comment: Costas answer should resolve your problem.

Comment: @АлександрБогомяков if Costas comment fixed your answer please spare a moment updating it and don't forget to mention the author of a fix.

Comment: could you please explain the following command                     sed ":a;s/|\(|\|$\)/|$(date +%Y_%m_%d)\1/;ta"